# Add column to postgres table using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to add a column to an existing postgres table using psycopg2.

`add_column` takes two arguments: `column_name` and `data_type`.

I currently get the following error: `syntax error at or near "VALUES"` in line 6:

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong? Cheers!

```
import psycopg2
from config import config

def add_column(column_name, data_type):
  #  """Add a new column to the vendors table"""
    sql = """ALTER TABLE vendors ADD COLUMN column_name data_type VALUES (%s, %s);"""

    conn = None
    try:
        params = config()
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql, (column_name, data_type,))
        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    add_column("test_name", "VARCHAR")
```

Comment: Your query has a superfluous comma in `VALUES (%s, %s,)`

Comment: Cheers for the quick response! I removed the comma, but the error remained. Edited my code accordingly.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-altertable.html There is vo VALUES in alter table. (what would it mean?)

Comment: @wildplasser. Actually there is, but it is used for partitions not adding a new column.

Comment: oops. But I don't think that was OP's intention.

Comment: `VALUES` is not valid in this context. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Try changing the sql query to be `sql = """ALTER TABLE vendors ADD COLUMN %s %s;"""`

Comment: Thanks! I need to provide values for the two variables: column_name and data_type. If I remove VALUES, the new column is added with name "column_name"

Comment: @Kishore That removed the error, cheers!

Next problem though: How would I need to write add_column("test_name", "VARCHAR") in the very last line?

Written as it is they show up as 'test_name' and 'VARCHAR'. If I remove the quotes I get the error 

NameError: name 'test' is not defined

Comment: You can't use `%s` for identifiers and data type strings it is only for data values.. If you want to build dynamic SQL see [SQL](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html).